# App Center. How launch creating a new one build via ps1 (PowerShell)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

If I created builds from Bitrise, I can launch builds via ps1.

for example:

```
$postParams = '{"hook_info":{"type":"bitrise","api_token":"AQKgU--wYxRIqpZqAkIJ1A"},"build_params":{"branch":"develop"}}' $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.bitrise.io/app/32363315d0fd1/build/start.json -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

How implement it for App Center? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The following powershell syntax can be used to create new builds in App Center, just replace the variables with your own. The url of your app will contain the user and app variables. You can create an api token in your [account settings](https://appcenter.ms/settings/apitokens).

```
$branch = 'master'
$user = 'exampleUser'
$app = 'exampleApp'
$token = '1234567a7c13234567c9f512346'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/$($user)/$($app)/branches/$($branch)/builds" -Method "POST" -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json"; "X-API-Token"="$($token)"; "Content-Type"="application/json"};
```

Comment: but this method needs  this model :    {
  "sourceVersion": "string",
  "debug": true
}